# Verificar se e-mail é válido?

Tags: c#

Estou usando essa função para verificar:

```
public static bool IsEmail(string strEmail)
{
    string strModelo = "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(strEmail, strModelo))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

E o seguinte para chamar a função (no método do botão `Salvar_Click`), esse está dentro de outro `if` que verifica se o telefone tem 10 dígitos (coloquei um dentro do outro pra não ter dois caminhos distintos para salvar o registro), e isso não é empecilho, ele sempre entrará nesse `if`, pois telefone é campo obrigatório:

```
if (emailTextBox.Text == "") // se o campo tiver vazio
{
    this.Validate(); //ele salva
    this.clientesBindingSource.EndEdit();
    Bloq(); //Blod desativa os TextBox
    this.add.Enabled = true; // ativa o botao de Add Novo 
    mbox.msbox.sucesso("Registro salvo.", "Sucesso"); //Exibe um aviso
}
else if (IsEmail(emailTextBox.Text) == false) // se retornar que email é falso
{
    mbox.msbox.erro("Email inválido.", "Erro"); //mensagem de erro
}
else
{ //se não (caso retorne true), salva o registro
    this.Validate();
    this.clientesBindingSource.EndEdit();
    Bloq(); // bloqueia campos
    this.add.Enabled = true; //ativa botao add
    mbox.msbox.sucesso("Registro salvo.", "Sucesso"); //mensagem de sucesso
}
```

Pra mim não há nada de errado com o código, mas não funciona, ele aceita e-mails como `sasadad`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vi o seu código não impede que o usuário prosiga, pois ele não cancela a ação do usuário quando o mesmo insere um valir inválido.
Recomendo que coloquer as análises no evento Validating do campo e coloque e.Cancel = true quando o usuário fizer algo errado, assim:

```
else if (IsEmail(emailTextBox.Text) == false)
{
    mbox.msbox.erro("Email inválido.", "Erro"); //mensagem de erro
    e.Cancel = true; // Cancela qualquer ação do usuário. Só permitindo que ele concerte o erro.
}
```